# Active nav color but different color in submenu

Tags: jquery

Hello i have this js script to get the url and show an active link on main nav menu and in sub menu. The only problem is that if i click a link in main menu and get the active color for that link then the sub menu will also show that same color. I dont want the sub menu links to show this color, i dont want the submenu link color to change before i click a link in the sub menu.

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
        var url = window.location.href;
        $('.ribbon a').filter(function() {
                return this.href == url;
            })
            .closest('li').addClass('current_yes').addClass('sub_current_yes');
 });
```

[You can see the menu here](http://test3.fcab.se/responsive_menu_test/index.html)

Comment: can you create a jsfiddle?

Comment: try doing .current_yes > a instead of .current_yes a in your css file

Comment: Sushil this worked. So simple. Thank you so much. :)

Comment: let me post this as an answer and you can mark it as an answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

your css file is applying the class to all the `'a'` the tags inside the `current_yes` class, i.e to all the siblings. to apply it only on to the immediate siblings try replacing `.current_yes a` in your CSS file with `.current_yes > a`